# Wrong Number of Arguments (3 for 2) when using Devise Authentication Gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, rubygems

I did some research and I think the error is due to use of different argument conventions in Rails 3.1 as opposed to 3.0.  How exactly should I go about fixing this?

```
wrong number of arguments (3 for 2)
```

Extracted source (around line #3):

```
1: <h2>Sign in</h2>
2: 
3: <%= form_for(resource_name, resource, :url => session_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
4:   <p><%= f.label :email %></p>
5:   <p><%= f.text_field :email %></p>
6:
```

[The full trace is here](https://gist.github.com/1577704)

This occurred while I tried to look up "/users/sign_in" with using the Devise gem.  If this is unfixable how the heck would I downgrade my rails to 3.0?  I tried changing the rails version in the gem file to 3.0.4 but it just threw me an error that my "activesupport" could not find a proper match.

Comment: you are using devise 1.1rc0. it's pretty old. try to upgrade it to 1.5 for example

Comment: Did you try changing your form_for to `<%= form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => session_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>` ?

Comment: I have this error with Devise 2.0.1 and Rails 3.1.1 RC1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot just change the rails version and think its done. In fact, the Devise has released [2.0.0](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To%3a-Upgrade-to-Devise-2.0). Try that if you feel thats some bug. I am myself using Rails 3.1 and i am not facing any issues as such.